Swiper library zoom magnification issue
I am using Swiper in my Vue project, and I've encountered an issue when trying to use the zoom feature with images that have a tall aspect ratio. The zoom functionality doesn't seem to work properly, especially when the height of the image exceeds the viewport or the container size. The image is not scaling as expected, and sometimes it gets misaligned or displays incorrectly.
I have tried the usual solutions such as setting object-fit and using the zoom module, but the issue persists with tall images. Could you please suggest a solution or guide me on how to resolve this problem?
Thank you for your help!
 <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
  <img src="/images/long.jpg" :alt="item.alt" />
</div>


const setSwiper = async () => {
        await nextTick();
        const option: SwiperOptions = {
            speed: 200,
            modules: [Navigation, Zoom],
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.button-next',
                prevEl: '.button-prev',
            },
            autoHeight: true,
            loop: flyerViewerInfo.value.tabs.length >= 2,
            ...(flyerViewerInfo.value.zoom && {
                zoom: {
                    maxRatio: 5,
                    minRatio: 1,
                },
            }),
            watchOverflow: true,
            on: {
                init: (swiper) => {
                    selectedId.value = Number($route.query.tabId) || flyerViewerInfo.value.tabs[swiper.realIndex].id;
                },
                realIndexChange: debounce((swiper: Swiper) => {
                    selectedId.value = flyerViewerInfo.value.tabs[swiper.realIndex].id;
                }, 200),
                zoomChange: (swiper, scale) => {
                    swiper.allowTouchMove = scale <= 1;
                },
            },
        };

        viewerSwiper.value = new Swiper(leafletViewer.value, option);
    };


